# Moving a div on scrolldown

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to move and fadeout a div on scrolling down, the fadeout effect is ok, but can't make it move left.

Any help?
Thanks!!!

Here's a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/z7E9u/1203/

```
var moveStart=100 // 100px scroll or less will equiv to 1 opacity
,moveUntil=900 // 900px scroll or more will equiv to 0 opacity
,moving = $('#fading')
;

$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
var moveoffset = $(document).scrollTop(),
    right=0
;
if( moveoffset<=moveStart ){
    right=0;
}else if( moveoffset<=moveUntil ){
    right=500-moveoffset/moveUntil;
}
//    fading.css('opacity',opacity).html(opacity);
fading.css('right',right);
});
```

Comment: cant make it move lefT?

Comment: Yes. Can't make it move left.

Comment: Please explain. what do you want ??

Comment: If you check out the fiddle example, you will see a blue div on the top, that fades out when you scrolldown. What I need to achieve is move the blue div to the left in an animated way on scrolldown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to `fade & move` an element to the left.
You first need to get the % amount of a scrollTop position in relation to a fixed value (900).

To **convert 900 to 100%** and retrieve the current **scrollTop %** you need this math:

```
currentPercent = Math.ceil( DocScrollTop * 100 / maxValue ); // Current percent (0-100)
```

so in your code should be like:

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/z7E9u/1208/)***

```
var max = 900,
    $el = $('#fading');

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var scrollPerc = Math.ceil($(this).scrollTop() * 100 / max);
    $el.css({
       opacity : 1-scrollPerc/100, // 1 to 0
       right   : scrollPerc+"%"    // 0% to 100%
    });
});
```

Comment: Roko, that example is great. But in case I just need to move the div 400px to the left, how do I set that limit?.